# Sending data from LKM to userspace

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have a Linux Kernel Module that generates data and I'd like to send that data to a userspace application. What are the options and what pros/cons do they have?

The data could be, let's say, 100 structs of a few char[] and a few int[] per second.

Also, if possible (not mandatory), I'd like those structs to get to userland in the same order as they are generated in the LKM.

Comment: This isn't constructive. "What's the best?" doesn't usually elicit good answers.

Comment: If you wish, replace it with "what are the options and what pros/cons do they have", I'll choose then which one fits best my needs :)

Comment: If *you* replace it, it might save the question from closure.

Comment: Perhaps, this discussion is also worth looking at: stackoverflow.com/questions/11501527

Answer (score 2):

Create a character driver and use the read function to return this.  By far, the absolute best tutorial for this is in [LDD3 (Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition)](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3) which, hey! you can download for free!  So you fill out your struct file_operations and populate these fields:

```
static const struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .owner =    THIS_MODULE,
    .read =     my_read,
    .open =     my_open,
    .release =  my_release,
};
```

Pass that puppy to cdev_init(), etc.  So that's where you spew your data (in my_read())

EDIT: Oh yeah, and I own the physical book of this and it's definitely one of my most worn from use, toting around, etc.

EDIT2: Ahh, so you want pros & cons now eh? :)  I would say that the biggest pro of a character driver is that you don't have to get a syscall number from Torvolds. :)  Well, then again, you don't have to do that if you aren't trying to distribute your patch.  A character driver is very straight forward and easy to implement.  You can also use an ioctl if you want the userland app to be able to request different data and have that data returned only upon request.  Alternatively, you can have the userland app write a request and only receive data from your read function when it gets a request, but I'm presuming you just want a constant data spew.  In that case, just have your read function write (to userland) everything it gets from whatever part of your module it comes from, as it gets it and in the order you want to send it.

One more thought, if you're dealing with very large amounts of data and are encountering bottlenecks, you may want to consider writing it to your user-space app via mmaped memory.  However, I honestly don't have great expertise in that particular area.

Oh yeah, also keep in mind that your struct file_operations functions can sleep and maybe other parts of your module can't. just a note

Comment: Thank you, but I have the same concern about this way as in my comment in the another question. (userspace having to call/search for data constantly instead of getting it on event basis). Is there a way to achieve sending data and making userland notice that via events instead of polling?

Answer (score 1):

You can try passing structure which will contain the buffer pointer & the size of the buffer. But the same structure should also be defined in both user-space application & inside your system-call's code in kernel.

```
     struct new_struct
        {
           void *p;  //set this pointer to your buffer...
           int size;
        };
        //from user-application...

        int main()
        {
           ....
           struct new_struct req_kernel;
           your_system_call_function(...,(void *)&req_kernel,...);
           // here u can get the data which is copied from kernel-space in req_kernel                      structure.
        }


........................................................................................


  //this is inside your kernel...
     your_system_call(...,char __user optval,...)
     {
            .....
            struct new_struct req;
           // fill the data in the resq structure. which will be access in user-space.
            if (copy_to_user(&req, optval, sizeof(req)))

            return -EFAULT;
            //now you have the address or pointer & size of the buffer
            //which you want in kernel with struct req...
    }
```

**refer to http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html**

Comment: You got it wrong. I need to copy from kernel to user, not from user to kernel. Or will that work for kernel to user too?

Comment: @alexandernst yes it works in both ways...use copy_to_user();

Comment: One more thing. This design makes my userland app have to search/look for data. Is there any way I could send that data from the LKM instead of having userland call ```your_system_call``` constantly? (Something like DBus)

Comment: @alexandernst i think, if need to get the data from kernel to user-space application then any how the user-app should be aware of the state that the data is present or not. So u need to call syscall. Else its possible that u can use memory map then try polling for data to do ur job. but its complicated.!!!

Comment: I was thinking more about some design like DBus where my app will expose a DBus path and the kernel module will send data to userland via that DBus path. Is something like that possible?

Comment: @alexandernst if u are interested in DBus then have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643483/dbus-on-kernel-to-user-space it may help u!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28956/discussion-between-akp-and-alexandernst)